# Appending Text to a file path

Tags: c#, winforms

This is probably a simple question, I'm writing a WinForms C# application in VS 2012. I was wondering if there a way to add an extension such as .csv to some writing in a textbox. Say the user wrote in C:\Users\Desktop\filename but left out the .csv part of the path. Is there any way to add the .csv after an execute button is clicked?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Path.ChangeExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx).

```
// Nota bene: Path.ChangeExtension does not change textBox1.Text directly (or any
//            argument given), you MUST use the result if you care about it.
string newPath = Path.ChangeExtension(textBox1.Text, "csv");
```

The period is optional, and the filename component need not include an extension.

As a future reference, if you can think of *something* you need to do with a path to a file or a directory...it exists in [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path_methods.aspx). Rare for there not to be support for a common task in that class.

Comment: I'm using a streamwriter that's like finalOutput = new StreamWriter(textBox1.Text); but it won't work with this for some reasosn.

Comment: Do you assign the new path back to `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: Should I write like, finalOutput = new StreamWriter(newPath)?

Comment: That would be correct. `textBox1.Text` was not passed by reference, hence `Path.ChangeExtension` had no means of modifying the reference. In C#, pretty much assume that if you are using a string (an "immutable object") the *only* means of updating *that instance* is to store a result *back into* that instance. (Just like `x + 1` doesn't actually increment `x`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change a valid extension in the string, you could do it like this instead:

```
// first test for an extension
if(!Path.HasExtension(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
{
    // then add on '.csv' if one does not exist
    string path = Path.ChangeExtension(textBox1.Text.Trim(), ".csv");

    // ... use path ...
}
```

Comment: (+1) I've updated this to use a 'proper' way to add/replace an extension, with some explanation as to how yours differs from mine.

Comment: can somebody tell me why am i downvoted twice? This is ridiculous. If there is a problem atleast let me know